# Native type binding source / How to fill a DevExpress GridControl with a List of strings?

Tags: c#, devexpress, datasource, gridcontrol

I normally have no problem with binding a DataSource to a GridControl. I usually so something like this:

```
myGrid.DataSource = myList // BindingList<ComplexObject>
colMyStrings.FieldName = "PropertyNameOfComplexObject";
```

and it works fine. I can add and delete rows from the grid and they will get added to / deleted from the DataSource "myList". So I basically always see what's in my List.

But now I don't have a `List<ComplexObject>`, where the Generic Type has Properties, but I have a List filled with strings.

```
BindingList<string>
```

When I try to bind the List to my grid, it wont get that the strings themselves are what i want bound to the rows of my column and since string doesn't have any properties, there is nothing I can fill the columns `.FieldName` with.

I know I could use a wrapper class to solve this problem, but I don't find this solution to be very nice.

Is there a way to tell the column, that the data it should use is the Objects, in this case the strings, themselves?

### Update 1

This is something I tried. I thought if I could make my own GridControl and override the setter for the DataSource Property, I could make an internal Wrapper so that anyone who uses it wont need do so. This kind of works. I can add my `DataSource BindingList<string>` now, but for some reason I cant edit the values. I don't know why.

Here is the code:

```
public partial class NativeTypeGrid : DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl
{
    public NativeTypeGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public override object DataSource
    {
        get
        {
            return base.DataSource;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value is IBindingList)
            {
                Type GenericType;
                IBindingList myList = (IBindingList) value;
                BindingList<Wrapper> wrappedList = new BindingList<Wrapper>();
                GenericType = myList.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
                if(GenericType.IsPrimitive || GenericType == typeof(string))
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        object obj = myList[i];
                        wrappedList.Add(new Wrapper(ref obj));
                    }

                    base.DataSource = wrappedList;
                }
                else
                {
                    base.DataSource = value;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                base.DataSource = value;
            }
        }
    }

    internal class Wrapper
    {
        private object _NativeTypeProperty;

        public Wrapper()
        {
            _NativeTypeProperty = "SomeValueForInitialization";
        }

        public Wrapper(ref object nativeType)
        {
            _NativeTypeProperty = nativeType;
        }

        public object NativeTypeProperty
        {
            get { return _NativeTypeProperty; }
            set { _NativeTypeProperty = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

### Update 2

I already figured out why it won't get any by the user added objects.
Of course it doesn't work since adding an Object to the DataSource uses the basic/empty constructor, which in turn means that my DataSource doesn't have that connection to the original List, which is the one I want the new objects to be in. I will work on this and update again.

### Update 3

Couldn't think of any better solution, so I went with the initial approach and built a wrapper class for my strings. Looks a little bit like this:

```
class StringWrapper{
    public String MyString{ get; set;}
}

myGrid.DataSource = new BindingList<StringWrapper>();
```

I would still be happy to use another approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `"Column"` as `Column.FieldName`.
Here is example:

```
var myList = new List<string>() { "String 0", "String 1", "String 2" };

myGrid.DataSource = myList;
colMyStrings.FieldName = "Column";
```

However you cannot add or modify the values in `GridView`, because DevExpress team does not implemented the properly usage of this case and you can only delete values.

But if you want to manipulate with your list by using `GridControl`, then you need to create list wrapper, not string wrapper. For this purpose you can implement `IBindingList` interface which is allowed as `DataSource` according to [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2385).
Here is example of simple list wrapper that implements `IBindingList` interface:

```
public class ListWrapper<T> : IBindingList
{
    private IList<T> _wrappedList;

    public ListWrapper(IList<T> wrappedList)
    {
        _wrappedList = wrappedList;
    }

    #region IBindingList implementation
    #region Necessary members
    public object this[int index]
    {
        get { return new Wrapper(this, index); }//This wrapper have the Value property which is used as FieldName.
        set { Insert(index, value); }
    }

    public object AddNew()
    {
        _wrappedList.Add(default(T));

        return new Wrapper(this, Count - 1);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        _wrappedList.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public int Count { get { return _wrappedList.Count; } }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new ListWrapperEnumerator(this);
    }

    private class Wrapper
    {
        private readonly ListWrapper<T> _listWrapper;
        private readonly int _index;

        public Wrapper(ListWrapper<T> listWrapper, int index)
        {
            _listWrapper = listWrapper;
            _index = index;
        }

        public T Value
        {
            get { return _listWrapper._wrappedList[_index]; }
            set { _listWrapper._wrappedList[_index] = value; }
        }
    }

    private class ListWrapperEnumerator : IEnumerator
    {
        private readonly ListWrapper<T> _listWrapper;
        private int _currentIndex;

        public ListWrapperEnumerator(ListWrapper<T> listWrapper)
        {
            _listWrapper = listWrapper;

            Reset();
        }

        public object Current
        {
            get { return _listWrapper[_currentIndex]; }
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            return _currentIndex++ < _listWrapper.Count;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            _currentIndex = -1;
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region Optional members
    private bool GetValue(object value, out T result)
    {
        if (value is T)
        {
            result = (T)value;

            return true;
        }

        var wrapper = value as Wrapper<T>;
        if (wrapper != null)
        {
            result = wrapper.Value;

            return true;
        }

        result = default(T);
        return false;
    }

    public int Add(object value)
    {
        T result;

        if (GetValue(value, out result))
        {
            _wrappedList.Add(result);
            return _wrappedList.Count - 1;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _wrappedList.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(object value)
    {
        T result;

        if (GetValue(value, out result))
            return _wrappedList.Contains(result);

        return false;
    }

    public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        for (int listIndex = 0; listIndex < _wrappedList.Count; listIndex++)
        {
            int arrayIndex = listIndex + index;

            if (arrayIndex >= array.Length)
                return;

            array.SetValue(_wrappedList[listIndex], arrayIndex);
        }
    }

    public int IndexOf(object value)
    {
        T result;

        if (GetValue(value, out result))
            return _wrappedList.IndexOf(result);

        return -1;
    }

    public void Insert(int index, object value)
    {
        T result;

        if (GetValue(value, out result))
            _wrappedList.Insert(index, result);
    }

    public void Remove(object value)
    {
        T result;

        if (GetValue(value, out result))
            _wrappedList.Remove(result);
    }
    #endregion
    #region Settings
    public bool AllowEdit { get { return true; } }

    public bool AllowNew { get { return true; } }

    public bool AllowRemove { get { return true; } }

    public bool IsFixedSize { get { return false; } }

    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }

    public bool SupportsChangeNotification { get { return false; } }

    public bool SupportsSearching { get { return false; } }

    public bool SupportsSorting { get { return false; } }
    #endregion
    #region Not used members
    public void AddIndex(PropertyDescriptor property) { }

    public void ApplySort(PropertyDescriptor property, ListSortDirection direction) { }

    public int Find(PropertyDescriptor property, object key) { return -1; }

    public void RemoveIndex(PropertyDescriptor property) { }

    public void RemoveSort() { }

    public bool IsSorted { get { return false; } }

    public bool IsSynchronized { get { return false; } }

    public ListSortDirection SortDirection { get { return default(ListSortDirection); } }

    public PropertyDescriptor SortProperty { get { return null; } }

    public object SyncRoot { get { return null; } }

    public event ListChangedEventHandler ListChanged;
    #endregion
    #endregion
}
```

You can use this wrapper as follows:

```
var myList = new BindingList<string>() { "String 0", "String 1", "String 2" });

myGrid.DataSource = new ListWrapper<string>(myList);
colMyStrings.FieldName = "Value";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, that is not exactly what I was looking for. I accually want to modify the strings in my List without needing to handle a bunch of events or somethink like that, thats why I wanted to use the Grid in the first place.
I would be happy to hear more suggestions so if you have any, please let me know.
Thanks again.

Comment: @Smogen What have you tried? Can you add your solutions to question?

Comment: I added something I tried to the question.
This is a, not very nice, workaround so that I dont have to manually build a Wrapper class, but as I mentioned above, it doesnt work properly. I want to alter the DataSource via the grid so that it all works automatically just by me giving it the right DataSource.

Comment: @Smogen With a wrapper class for values you will be not able to add, modify or delete values in your original `BindingList`. If you want to alter the `BindingList` by `GridControl` then you need to create list wrapper. Take a look at my answer, I have added a simple implementation of list wrapper.