# Webforms - DataBinding() GridView - how to bind a List that has a List<string> property?

Tags: c#, linq, gridview, binaryfiles

I tried reading other posts about binding list properties, but the answers provided were too advanced for me to understand. I'm not sure what to do myself to be able to manipulate the output.

I am trying to bind my list of books in gridview on webforms, but the property **Authors** is obviously not writing the names of the authors. 
I get this instead :
`` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] `` 
And if **AutogenerateColumns** is set to true, then **Authors** column is not generated at all.

```
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<string> Authors { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
```

```
output = from b in Books
         where b.Author.Any(a => a.ToUpper().Contains(InputBook.Text.ToUpper()))
         select b;

         gridview.DataSource = output.ToList();
         gridview.DataBind();
```

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns><asp:BoundField HeaderText="Author" DataField="Author" /></Columns>
    <Columns><asp:BoundField HeaderText="Title" DataField="Title" /></Columns>
    <Columns><asp:BoundField HeaderText="ISBN" DataField="ISBN" /></Columns>
   <Columns><asp:BoundField HeaderText="Price" DataField="Price" /></Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Not 100% sure if that might help but I had a similar problem a long time ago and stopped working on it. I didnt get an answer for the pefrect solution however in the question I documented a not-so-pretty solution in the end, similar to your proposed solution. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32646177/native-type-binding-source-how-do-i-fill-a-devexpress-gridcontrol-with-a-list

Comment: I'm sorry! I bumped my own post by answering myself since someone commented earlier and deleted his comment. I wanted to answer so that if in the future someone has a similar problem, they would have a solution. But thanks for helping anyways my friend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was told to convert my property `List<string> Authors` to a class Authors that has a property of `List<string> Names`. So when you want to bind it to your gridview, it will call the `override ToString()` method. There you could do a for loop and write a simple string.